# How to wrap a text (break its lines as needed to show the whole content) in a GridView's footer

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I have a Grid Tile made by this code:

```dart
child: GridTile(
  child: Hero(
  tag: "${item}",
  child: setIcon(item)
  footer: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         height: 50,
         color: Colors.white70,
         child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           children: [
             Text(
                item.elemento == null
                   ? item.video['nome']
                   : item.elemento.name,
                 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                 style: TextStyle(
                 color: Theme
                   .of(context)
                   .textTheme
                   .caption
                   .color,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
          ),
         ),
 ),
),
```

It gives me this result :

[image]

How could I adapt my text to show the entire text (without '...')? As you can see, it shows only some characters, I wanna show all the word. How could I do this?

**UPDATE**
With this code it still equal the photo

```
footer: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    item.elemento == null
                                        ? item.video['nome']
                                        : item.elemento.name,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .caption
                                          .color,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

And with this code it throws line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
footer: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    item.elemento == null
                                        ? item.video['nome']
                                        : item.elemento.name,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .caption
                                          .color,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the text with the Row widget as a parent to that it takes max width

Comment: see my update..

Comment: check out the example do not change the column that's ok just check the example where I have placed the expanded widget as the parent and remove this overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

Comment: see my updates, please. It didn't worked here

Comment: change the row to column

Comment: Sorry, in the second example is column instead of row...

Comment: overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, remove this from the second example

Comment: If I keep Column and remove the textOverflow.. it throws that `Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Comment: and don't show any text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229111/discussion-between-sagar-acharya-and-armstrong).

Comment: join the discussion in chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example

```
// Add this widget as a parent to the text widget.
Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                    'asdfbnasdfmlqkw asknfwa wfn iwqf  wfnwf qwoif qwoif qwef wfoiqwefnwefwq ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

remove

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

from the text widget parameters

just add the expanded widget as a parent to the text widget as shown below

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text), loved the package

```
AutoSizeText(
            text,
            //dont set it, will resize the text to fit up to two lines
            // overflow: TextOverflow.visible,

            //set how many lines your text can have
            maxLines: 2,
            //set hoow big text can be
            maxFontSize: 30,
            //set how small the text can be.. 
            minFontSize: 14,
),
```